Data is not refetching and rerender when another user login
When the user logs in, they will fetch their worksheet list according to the creator's ID. When they log out and another user logs in, the list of worksheet data should change according to the ID of the logged-in user.
The worksheet data list from the previous user still exists.
Here is my Github. Here's where my problem is. (1 and 2)
home_view.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/models/worksheet_state.dart';

import 'package:pde_worksheet/routes/app_router.gr.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/utils/date_time_utils.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/src/home/home_controller.dart';

@RoutePage(name: 'HomeRoute')
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView>
    with AutoRouteAwareStateMixin<HomeView> {
  final HomeController _controller = HomeController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<WorksheetState> _allWorksheets = [];
  List<WorksheetState> _displayedWorksheets = [];
  int _currentChunkIndex = 0;
  final int _chunkSize = 10;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
    _controller.decodeToken().then((_) {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.addListener(_updateState);
  }

  void _updateState() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _loadNextChunk() {
    final nextChunk = _allWorksheets
        .skip(_currentChunkIndex * _chunkSize)
        .take(_chunkSize)
        .toList();
    setState(() {
      _displayedWorksheets.addAll(nextChunk);
      _currentChunkIndex++;
    });
  }

  void _editItem(int id) async {
    AutoRouter.of(context)
        .navigate(WorksheetRoute(itemId: id, onWorksheetChanged: fetchData));
  }

  void _createNewItem() async {
    AutoRouter.of(context)
        .navigate(WorksheetRoute(onWorksheetChanged: fetchData));
  }

  void _deleteItem(int id) {
    print('Deleting item at id: $id');
  }

  void fetchData() {
    _controller.fetchWorksheets().then((worksheets) {
      setState(() {
        _allWorksheets = worksheets;
        _displayedWorksheets.clear();
        _currentChunkIndex = 0;
        _loadNextChunk();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _controller.removeListener(_updateState);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
            label: const Text("Profile"),
            onPressed: () {
              AutoRouter.of(context).navigate(const ProfileRoute());
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
        valueListenable: _controller.isLoading,
        builder: (context, isLoading, child) {
          if (isLoading) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            itemCount: _displayedWorksheets.length + 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index == _displayedWorksheets.length) {
                return _currentChunkIndex * _chunkSize < _allWorksheets.length
                    ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                    : const SizedBox.shrink();
              }
              final worksheet = _displayedWorksheets[index];
              final startTime = formatDateTime(worksheet.startTime!);
              final endTime = formatDateTime(worksheet.endTime!);
              return Card(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                elevation: 4.0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _controller.showEditDeleteDialog(
                      context,
                      _controller.decodedToken['accessRight'],
                      () => _editItem(worksheet.id),
                      () => _deleteItem(worksheet.id),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          title: Text(
                            'Worksheet Number: ${worksheet.worksheetNumber}',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text('Room: ${worksheet.room}'),
                          trailing: const Icon(Icons.assignment),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text('Start Time: $startTime'),
                        Text('End Time: $endTime'),
                        const Divider(height: 20, thickness: 1),
                        const Text(
                          'Technicians:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        ...worksheet.technicians.map((tech) => ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                              title: Text(tech.fullName),
                            )),
                        const Divider(height: 20, thickness: 1),
                        const Text(
                          'Softwares:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        ...worksheet.softwares.map((software) => ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.computer),
                              title: Text(software.description!),
                            )),
                        const Divider(height: 20, thickness: 1),
                        const Text(
                          'Hardwares:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        ...worksheet.hardwares.map((hardware) => ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.memory),
                              title: Text(hardware.description!),
                            )),
                        const Divider(height: 20, thickness: 1),
                        const Text(
                          'Networks:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        ...worksheet.networks.map((network) => ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.network_check),
                              title: Text(network.description!),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _createNewItem();
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        tooltip: 'Create Worksheet',
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

home_controller.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:pde_worksheet/models/worksheet_state.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/services/worksheet_service.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/store/store.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/utils/token_utils.dart';

class HomeController extends ChangeNotifier {
  final WorksheetService _worksheetService = WorksheetService();
  List<WorksheetState> worksheets = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> decodedToken = {};
  final ValueNotifier<bool> isLoading = ValueNotifier(false);

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    isLoading.dispose();
  }

  /// Fetches worksheets from the service and updates the state.
  Future<List<WorksheetState>> fetchWorksheets() async {
    try {
      isLoading.value = true;
      final fetchedWorksheets = await _worksheetService.getWorksheets();
      worksheets = fetchedWorksheets;
      filterWorksheets();
      return worksheets; // Return the list of worksheets
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error
      print('Error fetching worksheets: $e');
      return []; // Return an empty list in case of error
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }

  /// Decodes the token and filters worksheets based on user role.
  Future<void> decodeToken() async {
    try {
      final token = await _getToken();
      if (token != null) {
        decodedToken = JWT().decodeToken(token);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error
      print('Error decoding token: $e');
    }
  }

  /// Retrieves the token from secure storage.
  Future<String?> _getToken() async {
    try {
      return await SecureStorage.read('token');
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error
      print('Error getting token: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  /// Filters worksheets based on the user's role and ID.
  void filterWorksheets() {
    final userId = decodedToken['id'];
    final userRole = decodedToken['accessRight'];

    // desc order by createdAt
    worksheets.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt!.compareTo(a.createdAt!));

    worksheets = worksheets.where((worksheet) {
      if (userRole == 'SUPERADMIN' || userRole == 'ADMIN') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return worksheet.userId == userId;
      }
    }).toList();
  }

  void showEditDeleteDialog(
      BuildContext context, String role, Function onEdit, Function onDelete) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Edit or Delete Item'),
          content: Text('Choose an action'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                onEdit();
              },
              child: Text('Edit'),
            ),
            if (role == 'SUPERADMIN' || role == 'ADMIN')
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  onDelete();
                },
                child: Text('Delete'),
              ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


When the first user logs in

And another user logs in, it's not refetching the worksheets, and home is still showing the data from previous user.

I am trying to display data of users who are logged in, based on their ID and access rights.

From the code, it seems like you are trying to do lots at once using flutter widget circle.
I would suggest you first to use a State Management solution ( I recommend Bloc here or Getx here)
For your problem, you can use a stream that will keep the numbers updated
here is the updated code
home_view.dart





import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/models/worksheet_state.dart';

import 'package:pde_worksheet/routes/app_router.gr.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/utils/date_time_utils.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/src/home/home_controller.dart';

@RoutePage(name: 'HomeRoute')
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> with AutoRouteAwareStateMixin<HomeView> {
  final HomeController _controller = HomeController();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<WorksheetState> _allWorksheets = [];
  List<WorksheetState> _displayedWorksheets = [];
  int _currentChunkIndex = 0;
  final int _chunkSize = 10;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
    _controller.decodeToken().then((_) {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.addListener(_updateState);
    _controller.worksheetStream.listen((worksheets) {
      setState(() {
        _allWorksheets = worksheets;
        _displayedWorksheets.clear();
        _currentChunkIndex = 0;
        _loadNextChunk();
      });
    });
  }

  void _updateState() {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _loadNextChunk() {
    final nextChunk = _allWorksheets
        .skip(_currentChunkIndex * _chunkSize)
        .take(_chunkSize)
        .toList();
    setState(() {
      _displayedWorksheets.addAll(nextChunk);
      _currentChunkIndex++;
    });
  }

  void _editItem(int id) async {
    AutoRouter.of(context)
        .navigate(WorksheetRoute(itemId: id, onWorksheetChanged: fetchData));
  }

  void _createNewItem() async {
    AutoRouter.of(context)
        .navigate(WorksheetRoute(onWorksheetChanged: fetchData));
  }

  void _deleteItem(int id) {
    print('Deleting item at id: $id');
  }

  void fetchData() {
    _controller.fetchWorksheets().then((worksheets) {
      setState(() {
        _allWorksheets = worksheets;
        _displayedWorksheets.clear();
        _currentChunkIndex = 0;
        _loadNextChunk();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    _controller.removeListener(_updateState);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
            label: const Text("Profile"),
            onPressed: () {
              AutoRouter.of(context).navigate(const ProfileRoute());
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
        valueListenable: _controller.isLoading,
        builder: (context, isLoading, child) {
          if (isLoading) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            itemCount: _displayedWorksheets.length + 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index == _displayedWorksheets.length) {
                return _currentChunkIndex * _chunkSize < _allWorksheets.length
                    ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                    : const SizedBox.shrink();
              }
              final worksheet = _displayedWorksheets[index];
              final startTime = formatDateTime(worksheet.startTime!);
              final endTime = formatDateTime(worksheet.endTime!);
              return Card(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                elevation: 4.0,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    _controller.showEditDeleteDialog(
                      context,
                      _controller.decodedToken['accessRight'],
                      () => _editItem(worksheet.id),
                      () => _deleteItem(worksheet.id),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          title: Text(
                            'Worksheet Number: ${worksheet.worksheetNumber}',
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text('Room: ${worksheet.room}'),
                          trailing: const Icon(Icons.assignment),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text('Start Time: $startTime'),
                        Text('End Time: $endTime'),
                        const Divider(height: 20, thickness: 1),
                        const Text(
                          'Technicians:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        ...worksheet.technicians.map((tech) => ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
                              title: Text(tech.fullName),
                            )),
                        const Divider(height: 20, thickness: 1),
                        const Text(
                          'Softwares:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        ...worksheet.softwares.map((software) => ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.computer),
                              title: Text(software.description!),
                            )),
                        const Divider(height: 20, thickness: 1),
                        const Text(
                          'Hardwares:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        ...worksheet.hardwares.map((hardware) => ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.memory),
                              title: Text(hardware.description!),
                            )),
                        const Divider(height: 20, thickness: 1),
                        const Text(
                          'Networks:',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        ...worksheet.networks.map((network) => ListTile(
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.network_check),
                              title: Text(network.description!),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _createNewItem();
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        tooltip: 'Create Worksheet',
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

here is the home_controller.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/models/worksheet_state.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/services/worksheet_service.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/store/store.dart';
import 'package:pde_worksheet/utils/token_utils.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class HomeController extends ChangeNotifier {
  final WorksheetService _worksheetService = WorksheetService();
  List<WorksheetState> worksheets = [];
  Map<String, dynamic> decodedToken = {};
  final ValueNotifier<bool> isLoading = ValueNotifier(false);
  final StreamController<List<WorksheetState>> _worksheetStreamController = StreamController.broadcast();

  Stream<List<WorksheetState>> get worksheetStream => _worksheetStreamController.stream;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    isLoading.dispose();
    _worksheetStreamController.close();
  }

  Future<List<WorksheetState>> fetchWorksheets() async {
    try {
      isLoading.value = true;
      final fetchedWorksheets = await _worksheetService.getWorksheets();
      worksheets = fetchedWorksheets;
      filterWorksheets();
      _worksheetStreamController.add(worksheets);
      return worksheets;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching worksheets: $e');
      return [];
    } finally {
      isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> decodeToken() async {
    try {
      final token = await _getToken();
      if (token != null) {
        decodedToken = JWT().decodeToken(token);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error decoding token: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<String?> _getToken() async {
    try {
      return await SecureStorage.read('token');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error getting token: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  void filterWorksheets() {
    final userId = decodedToken['id'];
    final userRole = decodedToken['accessRight'];

    worksheets.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt!.compareTo(a.createdAt!));

    worksheets = worksheets.where((worksheet) {
      if (userRole == 'SUPERADMIN' || userRole == 'ADMIN') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return worksheet.userId == userId;
      }
    }).toList();
  }

  void showEditDeleteDialog(BuildContext context, String role, Function onEdit, Function onDelete) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Edit or Delete Item'),
          content: Text('Choose an action'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed:() {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            onEdit();
          },
          child: Text('Edit'),
        ),
        if (role == 'SUPERADMIN' || role == 'ADMIN')
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              onDelete();
            },
            child: Text('Delete'),
          ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
  }
}

hope it solves ur issue, all the best!

I'm sorry, The code you provided still doesn't work, it's still the same as mine, the data or the list is not fetching when another user logs in on the same device, it still shows data from the previous user

Is Riverpod equivalent to Bloc? I am utilizing Riverpod for the login process
